# rename a file with datetime stamp in a folder using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that creates text files in a folder. ex : C:\Folder1\20230425_1040_Myfile.txt The package runs once a day. Now I want to rename this file to myfile.txt and store into the same folder. Can I do this using file system task ? Can the file system task identify the file name dynamically? ( file name changes every day as it has a time stamp.)

Can you please help me? Thanks

I tried to use the file system task. However I am not able to give the file name dynamically.